# "5 часов назад эта учётная запись будет удалена"

Tags: дефект, локализация, удаление-профиля

Эм... что?

Скриншот:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Позвольте, а [meta-tag:инструменты-модератора]-то тут при чём?

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, это сообщение видно только вам и модераторам. Поэтому метка [meta-tag:инструменты-модератора] и стоит.

Comment: Оно должно быть видно каждому, кто удаляет свою учётную запись.

Comment: @Suvitruf модтулс тут, имхо, действительно не к месту. Так можно любую приватную инфу, доступную модам тегать модтулсами. Но это оооочень странно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я так и делаю )

Comment: @Suvitruf категорически не согласен

Comment: @αλεχολυτ   (｡•́︿•̀｡) ну ладно